# Is there a bug with the scoreboard for reputation right now?

Tags: bug, status-completed, reputation-leagues

Look at this: https://stackexchange.com/leagues/1/week/stackoverflow

kguest is in 3rd this week with 60 reputation and we're over halfway through the week?

Is this a bug, or am I confused by how the scoreboard works?

Comment: Something does seem to be a little off, especially considering it only recognizes one MSO user.

Comment: Yeah, you're right. I didn't think to look at the other scoreboards.

Comment: According to the all-time SO results, there are 16 users with 200+ reputation, and 717,825 users under 200.  Better withdraw your rep and put it under a mattress before the crash.

Comment: The "Top x pecrent" thing on users profiles has disappeared too. I'm not sure if it was like that when I first noticed the bug. Maybe they took it down because they're working on it.

Comment: @Paul we are working on it!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Should be fixed now.  The daily recalc apparently fell over halfway through, and then we cached the bad data even after it was repaired.

Comment: Thanks :) Looks like it's working now. The link saying "top x percent" on profiles' info section needs to be added back too :)

Comment: [Starx](http://stackoverflow.com/users/295264/starx) is gonna be **mighty** disappointed that he missed his fifteen minutes of fame as the number one SO user of all time.  His profile states humbly _A Nobody, Trying to be Somebody_.